# Can the pad and stylus product achieve every mouse action?

Tags: mouse

The pad ans stylus, for example, product of WACOM.

Can they achieve every actions which can be done by mouse?

For example: left-click, right click, moving pointer, drag and drop, scrolling.

Please don't vote to close it as irrelevant so quickly. I am suffering from finger pain due to too much clicking, then someone suggest I use a pad and stylus, so I am wondering whether it can avoid clicking/tapping by the fingers, at the same time provide me the basic function of a mouse.

Comment: About 4 years ago I thought I was going to have to have surgery to "fix" the pain I had in elbow, wrist and fingers from using a mouse repeatedly. I had read online about the Wacom pad being a good substitute for a mouse for people with RSD. I tried it and I am happy to say that it has almost cured my pain completely. I love my pad (I only use the pen version and not the touch version) and after spending a week or two getting used to it I can't live without it. It may not work for everyone but if you are having pain I would give it a try.

Comment: @BukHix makes an important point here: it takes a little getting used to.  Don't just try a stylus for five minutes; everything's clumsier at first as you adjust your whole way of working.

Comment: @BukHix Is the tablet expensive? I think most of the product of WACOM are targeted at some onliner drawer, and I would only need the basic function probably.

Comment: You can get the Pen Tablet for $69 and the Pen and Touch for $99 at many Best Buys. I have only ever used the Pen so I can't compare the two models but I can tell you this. I have tried to write and draw with the pad and the results have been poor (my problem not the pads) so I don't even try to use it for that. I use it as a  99.9% replacement of the mouse. I still keep a mouse plugged into the computer for .1% of the work I do, which is mostly when I am working with Crystal Reports where I need precision control of the pointer for sizing text boxes etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer: yes, all mouse actions are achievable with a graphics tablet and stylus.

More sophisticated answer: All mouse actions are achievable, but not all are equally easy.

**Easier with tablet:**
Drag-and-drop, box-select, all graphics / image editing work.  If your pad has macro buttons or programmable areas, some routine tasks *can* be made easier with well-chosen macro controls.

**Easier with mouse:**
Precise clicking on small areas.  Any action-based computer game (they're really not designed for tablets).  Some tasks which need frequent mouse/keyboard switching - I find it easier to go from keyboard to mouse than to pad.  (This is personal preference; try for yourself).

Scrolling can be a tossup depending on your pad; recent Wacom's have a pretty good programmable wheel, but I find mouse slightly easier.

Tablet/stylus uses very different hand motions and postures than the mouse, so it can help with some wrist injuries even if it's no easier to use.  A *good* tablet isn't always cheap, so try before you buy if possible - some people love them, others can't use them.